# ¿Necesitamos una guía para usar Stack Snippet?

Tags: discusión, stack-snippets

Por los votos positivos y debido a que algunas etiquetas se verían beneficiadas de incluir en enlace a la guía, he iniciado la adaptación o replicación de algunas publicaciones en inglés:

- [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/65)

---

Respondiendo a [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142607/65) hace un momento recordé que he observado errores similares en otras preguntas en lo que respecta al uso de Stack Snippet, por ejemplo

- Se incluyen etiquetas DOCTYPE header, body, etc. las cuáles no deberían incluirse, al menos así se indica en otros fiddles como jsFiddle que en http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#entering-code dice:

  > **Warning:** Please do not enter doctype, body etc. into the HTML panel. These tags are placed automatically.

  Traducción:

  > **Advertencia:** Por favor no incluya doctype, body etc. en el panel HTML. Estas etiquetas son agregadas automáticamente.
- Se incluyen etiquetas con atributos href usando URLs relativas a archivos que no son parte de Stack Overflow en español. En algunos casos en la consola del navegador se muestran mensajes de error indicando que no se pudo encontrar el archivo y en otros casos simplemente se ignora.

Busqué unos minutos una guía sobre Stack Snippet, pero no encontré advertencias como la mencionada arriba así que me pregunto y a Uds también

¿Necesitamos una guía de Stack Snippet similar a la guía de jsFiddle?

Referencias

- [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/1595451)
- [Feedback requested: Stack Snippets 2.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270944/1595451)
- [Add information on Stack Snippets to Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277340/1595451)

Comment: incluso ponen código php o similares o agregan jquery manualmente

Comment: Me parece que en algunos casos es necesario para comprender el código, aunque es cierto que algunas veces puede entorpecer la ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Considero que si, se puede retomar la pregunta que publicaste como base para el resto de la comunidad de modo que se pueda hacer referencia a ella, algo así como cuando recomendamos el [ask] y genera un enlace a dicha fuente de consulta.

¿Por qué?

- Aparte de las razones ya mencionadas por *Ruslan López* veo que algunos usuarios que si al conocen la ocupan de manera general; es decir tanto para tecnologías backend como frontend.
- Algunos otros siguen anexando enlaces a algún *fiddle* pues tratan de agregar una referencia de código HTML o CSS o JS para argumentar su publicación; sin saber que la plataforma lo ofrece y que a diferencia de servicios de terceros, el código que ellos incrusten aquí seguirá después de su publicación cosa que con enlaces externos no se puede garantizar.

Lo anterior ayudaría para que por ejemplo, cuando se hace el comentario de que responden solo con un enlace a un *fiddle* se les agregue en la zona de comentarios un enlace a tu publicación(*Ruben*) y comprendan que aquí mismo disponen de medios para hacerlo

Answer (score 2):

Yo considero que SÍ por las siguientes razones que he observado:

- muchos usuarios no saben como crearlos
- algunos usuarios tienen problemas sobre como editarlos
- algunos no saben que se puede tomar el snippet de la pregunta para la respuesta con un solo click
- considero que hay pocas preguntas en el meta acerca de los snippets debido a la ignorancia acerca de ellos.

Acerca de como hacerla... yo creo que lo más recomendable es una pregunta marcada como wiki de comunidad donde podamos relacionar fácilmente los problemas que aparezcan sobre como usarlos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. ¿Has visto [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/65) ?

Comment: @Rubén sí, y no está pensado en escenarios de uso, sino en mostrar algunas características por lo que quien lo lee no siempre infiere como sacarles provecho

Comment: ¿Qué escenarios de uso estás pensando que requieran o resulte conveniente tener una guía específica?

Comment: @Rubén en todos los escenarios posibles

Comment: El comentario es demasiado amplio :P